# List Centralization

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type

Is there a way to centralize commons lists (and their data) across site collections?

I understand content types  can be shared/published from the contenttypehub  but it does not look like this is something that can be done with lists which is a real bummer.

My only work around is to implement a  coded solution which may be the only way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: The only easy way of doing this is by abstracting your point of entance to the data.
Meaning creating SPFX applications and deploying them across a plethora of sites.
Nothing else has come to mind :'(

Comment: I figured it would be something like that.  I'm not up to speed on SPFX yet to do something like that but I can PowerShell the heck out of it easily.  Thanks.